# the Tangent Principle

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Feynman gave a geometric proof that planet's orbit around the sun is an ellipse, there's an youtube [episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdIjYBtnvZU&t=1058s) for that, and for the tricky part there's some discussion on [stackexchange physics forum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/644073/can-soneome-help-me-understand-this-part-of-the-feynmans-lost-lecture), a more formal explanation can be found from the paper [Paths of the planets](https://tlakoba.w3.uvm.edu/AppliedUGMath/auxpaper_planets_HallHigson.pdf) by R.H. Hall and  N. Higson.

However, Hall etc's paper used a "Tangent Principle", which says :

> If two curves (in polar coordinates) $r_1(θ)$ and $r_2(θ)$ have the
> same tangent at every $θ$, then they are the same, up to scaling.

I believe this is also implicitly used by Feynman. It sounds correct, however, how could one prove it?

Comment: "ellipse", not "eclipse"...

Comment: How do you mean by scaling? Do you mean dilation of the curve?

Comment: @JeanMarie sorry i always messed up these 2...

Comment: @Buraian I suppose it means https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)#Similar_triangles

Comment: On some thought, this only works if both axes are dilated the same amount. It is clear this is not true if it is unequal. For example consdier the affine transformation of circle into ellipse

Comment: Okay I wrote solution, have a look now

Comment: All he means, is that if two functions have the same derivative, they are the same, plus or minus a constant number.

Answer (score 1):

### Effect of scaling on tangent.

I think one would have to dilate both $x$ and $y$ axes the same amount for your argument. Consider the function $g(x,y) = (ax,by)$ , let us consider the position vector to the curve $\gamma(x,y)$ then in the scaled system it will be $g \circ \gamma(t)$. The tangent vector is given as:

$$ \frac{d}{dt} (g \circ \gamma(t) ) = \frac{d}{dt} ( a x(t), a y(t) ) = a \frac{d \gamma}{dt}$$

Hence, the tangent vector is parallel to the original under stretch/ squish. To recover the original statement that the curves will be the same upto scale, simply integrate the above equation.

Comment: i don't understand it, where is $r_1$, $r_2$ and $\theta$ from the question?

Comment: I did the calculation by taking a parameterization of a curve in cartesian coordinates but one needs to understand that coordinate transform and curve itself coordinate independent. Hence,my result is true for all coordinate though I calculated it in cartesian